# needle : node.js returning 500 on POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, needle.js

I have my own rest API, that internally calls an NLP API, for which I have to post some data on their URL. 
I am using needle to achieve this, but there's some error that I cannot catch, and my own api is returning 500 to the frontend.

Here is that part of my server.js code:

```
app.post('/api/get',function(req,res) {
  //console.log(req);
  console.log("here in post ");
  if(!req.body){
    return res.send(400);
  }
  //console.log(req.body.msg);
  var searchQuery =  req.body.msg;
  var options = { 'api-key' : '3080a0e0-1111-11e5-a409-7159d0ac8188' };

  needle.post('http://api.cortical.io:80/rest/text/keywords?retina_name=en_associative',searchQuery,options,function(err, resp){
    if(err){
      console.log('something went wrong :' + err);
    }
    console.log('Got :'+resp );
});
```

I reach `here in post` every time, but nothing after that. I am also curious that is this correct way to specify my api-key for the external API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using express 4.x, I am not sure whether you configured your express server but you need install body-parser and add the following lines in your express configuration:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

If you are using express 3.x version, you don't need to install body-parser:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

Now regarding your post route I edited it a little bit:

```
var config = require('./config');

app.post('/api/get', function (req, res) {
  var searchQuery = {
    q: req.body.msg
  };

  var NEEDLE_API_KEY = config.needle.API_KEY;
  var NEEDLE_URL = config.needle.URL;

  var options = {
    'api-key': NEEDLE_API_KEY
  };

  needle.post(NEEDLE_URL, searchQuery, options, function (err, needleResponse) {
    console.log(err || needleResponse.body);
    res.json(err || needleResponse.body);
  });

});
```

So I added a new file called **config.js** for purposes of having a reference for all your api keys, urls of your third party services.

```
module.exports = {
  needle: {
    API_KEY: process.env.NEEDLE_API_KEY,
    URL: 'http://api.cortical.io:80/rest/text/keywords?retina_name=en_associative'
  }
};
```

So when you run your server at the console, you should pass setting a value to your global environment variable called NEEDLE_API_KEY:

```
NEEDLE_API_KEY=666 node app.js
```

So in this way you are not saving any keys on your source code, you are saving keys in global environment variables that available only on the server machine.